# Пишет не найден индекс roles

Tags: авторизация, kohana

При регистрации, после записи пользователя в БД, ему прилагается роль:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user')->create_user($this->request->post(), array(
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    'email'             
                ));

                // Grant user login role
                $role = ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')); 
                $user->add('roles', $role);
```

Только вот у меня ошибка выходит в конце вот здесь:

```
$user->add('roles', $role);
```

пишет,

```
Undefined index: roles
```

что это за ошибка? Может кто нибудь знает?

Comment: Написали свой ``Model_User``?

Comment: Model_User у меня постой, только protected $_table_name = 'users'; и еще один ко многим добавил ulogin)) А что еще что то написать?))

Comment: Унаследоваться от ``Model_Auth_User``, либо прописать связи.  

    protected $_has_many = array(
 'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'User_Token'),
 'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
    );

Comment: кстати модель унаследован от Model_Auth_User)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, модуль был унаследован, но добавил  еще <pre>protected $_has_many = array(
'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'User_Token'),
'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
);
</pre>

Comment: почему у вас коды красиво смотрится)) у меня бррр((( никаких класов <pre> <code> не сработал))

Comment: Ставьте 4 пробела перед строчками кода.  
По теме. Универсального ответа у меня нет - проверяйте типы переменных, действительно ли та модель загружена в ``$user`` и прочее.